# special prices are not displayed

Tags: price, special-price

Before special prices were displaying on every page. Now special prices are not displaying in the site.

I set the product to use other themes. It's not displaying there also, so it is not a theme problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admin site : catalog->attribute ->Manage Attribute.
search for special price.

Check option

```
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end is yes or No.
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot fro your reply, yes : Visible on Product View Page on Front-end is yes . but still not displaying.

Comment: please visit this link : http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/snowman-markers/whiteboard-markers/snowman-whiteboard-markers-round-tip/non-alcohol-round-tip-black.html special price is displaying in "ADDITIONAL INFORMATION" on product view page, but its not displaying on catalog view page.

Comment: then go to your app/design/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/price.phtml and search for the "special price",  If  not get code from base file paste here

Comment: hi, in base theme also it's not displaying, not in modern, iphone, not displaying in any theme...  but before it was displaying. those products which i put special price are still showing "special price".

Comment: @BabyinMagento i cant get to your link, mysql errors..
try setting this if you are on a dedicated/vps `[mysqld]
set-variable=max_connections=250`

Comment: ok.. it seems like theme problem. 
Check wat @AnishaShaikh suggestd. Also check ur base theme files .. do they have the special price code or not .

Comment: @echoashu thanks  a lot for reply,  you can check the link now and special price not displaying in base theme also.

Comment: can you post the code snippet/ pastebin from the price phtml file of ur theme ?

Comment: hi , please check this price.phtml => http://pastebin.com/143wrPg4

Comment: hi @Anisha shaikh, i imported all products using csv file. 

In the "price" and "special price" columns , i swap the values of "price" and "special price" missly . thanks a lot....

Comment: hi @echoashu, i imported all products using csv file. 

In the "price" and "special price" columns , i swap the values of "price" and "special price" missly . thanks a lot....

Answer (score 2):

For me, this fixed it: 
Promotions > Catalog Price Rule > YOUR RULE > Actions > Enable Discount to Subproducts > YES >set the discount exactly the same as you did above it.

Comment: you are just fantastic :-)

Comment: This gets promotions working, not special prices, but good enough for what I needed, thanks.

Comment: Absolutely awesome! That fixed my problem, you saved my day, many many thanks.